# Imagemagick issue on Lion installed with Homebrew

Tags: imagemagick, paperclip, osx-lion, homebrew, freetype

I am trying to use the Paperclip gem on a Rails project so followed the docs and first installed Imagemagick using the Homebrew recipe.

I added to my model my attachment

```
has_attached_file :screenshot
```

This worked OK and the file uploads functioned as expected

I then wanted to add thumbnails to this, so again followed the docs and added to the model

```
  has_attached_file :screenshot, 
                :styles => { :medium => "300x300>",
                             :thumb => "100x100>" }
```

At this point the uploads no longer worked

I check the development logs and noticed this:

```
[32mCommand[0m :: identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/ky/r5gsdhbn6yggbglsg727cc900000gn/T/stream20120302-60051-eh17n7.png[0]'
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError:     
/var/folders/ky/r5gsdhbn6yggbglsg727cc900000gn/T/stream20120302-60051-eh17n7.png is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
```

At which point after some googling I thought it might be a problem with setting the default path as an environment variable

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

But I checked that this was correct using

```
which identify
```

And it returned this path

```
/usr/local/bin/identify
```

As expected

I then tried to run identify from the command line as a test and got this error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/identify
  Reason: Incompatible library version: identify requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 13.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

So I think my problem is not with paperclip, but rather the install of imageMagick via homebrew

I've tried everything suggested including

```
brew update
brew remove imagemagick
brew install imagemagick
```

But it hasn't helped i'm running Lion 10.7.2 and have installed the developer tools.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. Running a software update on the operating system resolved it for me. The version of libfree is out of date. Paperclip, ImageMagick and Homebrew were all working fine.

Comment: Thanks jmejia - you are right updating operating system & developer tools fixed it.

Answer (score 10):

There's a simpler solution.  Either install freetype:

```
brew install freetype
```

or, if it's already installed, then you need to recreate the links:

```
brew unlink freetype && brew link freetype
```

this will fix everything for you.  Well, not everything, but it'll at least fix this problem.

Comment: This worked and what you will see is: _> Natasha:Intervene natashagreen$ brew install freetype
Warning: freetype-2.5.3_1 already installed
_>Natasha:Intervene natashagreen$ brew unlink freetype && brew link freetype
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3_1... 1 symlinks removed
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3_1... 8 symlinks created
Natasha:Intervene natashagreen$ rake db:create
Natasha:Intervene natashagreen$

Answer (score 2):

After a software update on OSX MoutainLion ImageMagick stopped working for me too, but simply following the steps taken by Chris worked:

```
brew update
brew remove imagemagick
brew install imagemagick
```

Answer (score 0):

libfreetype was missing on my Mountain Lion (10.8) installation. In this case, installing XQuartz will replace the missing lib. http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps to someone:
After I try all these solution out there (update brew, reinstall imagemagick, unlink and link again) without success, came to my mind that **Paperclip might be the issue**. I just do:

```
 bundle update paperclip
```

And problem solved!

**Note**: imagemagick is working properly to me. When I run `identify -format %wx%h /path/to/a/file` from console, it works fine (I get the image's size). The 'identify' problem was happening only from my rails app.