# Rails - rMagic is not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, rmagick

I am trying ti use "carrierWave". I have installed "imagemagic" using homebrew and both rmagic and carrierwave gems.
When I run  `rails g uploader image` I get this error in terminal -

Will appreciate any help

Shani

> shannoga$ rails g uploader image
>   /Users/shannoga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/rmagick.rb:11:in
>   `require':
>   dlopen(/Users/shannoga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.bundle,
>   9): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (LoadError)
>
>   Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.5.dylib   Reason:
>   Incompatible library version: libMagickCore.5.dylib requires version
>   14.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 13.0.0 - /Users/shannoga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.bundle
>     from
>   /Users/shannoga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/rmagick.rb:11:in`
>   '    from
>   /Users/shannoga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in
>   `require'     from
>   /Users/shannoga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in`
>   block (2 levels) in require'     from
>   /Users/shannoga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in
>   `each'    from
>   /Users/shannoga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in`
>   block in require'    from
>   /Users/shannoga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in
>   `each'    from
>   /Users/shannoga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from
>   /Users/shannoga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:122:in
>   `require'     from
>   /Users/shannoga/SITES/ANGELS_APP_CMS/config/application.rb:7:in`'  from
>   /Users/shannoga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in
>   `require'     from
>   /Users/shannoga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in`
>   '    from script/rails:6:in `require'    from
>   script/rails:6:in`'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any one gets into this problem -
I was using mountain lion and had to manually install the latest xQuartz for mountain lion and every thing works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the latest xQuarts *and* running a system update worked for me. Related to this other post: [Imagemagick issue on Lion installed with Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537011/imagemagick-issue-on-lion-installed-with-homebrew)