# Identify error Paperclip and Imagemagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

I recently upgraded to osx 10.8 (Mtn Lion) and now I am having problems with Imagemagick. I get the following error when I try to upload a file:

```
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/nd/1cw0mqzj0nb3jv8psz_ht9cr0000gn/T/2011Spring20120803-530-2nr1jn.jpg[0]'
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /var/folders/nd/1cw0mqzj0nb3jv8psz_ht9cr0000gn/T/2011Spring20120803-530-2nr1jn.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/nd/1cw0mqzj0nb3jv8psz_ht9cr0000gn/T/2011Spring20120803-530-2nr1jn.jpg[0]'
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /var/folders/nd/1cw0mqzj0nb3jv8psz_ht9cr0000gn/T/2011Spring20120803-530-2nr1jn.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
```

I uninstalled / reinstalled homebrew and imagemagick. I even added the rmagick gem (which I didn't need before) but still get the above error.

```
brew install imagemagick
Error: imagemagick-6.7.7-6 already installed
```

Here is brew doctor output:

```
brew doctor
Warning: Setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH can break dynamic linking.
You should probably unset it.
Warning: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew's core.
Unless you know what you are doing, you should run:
  cd /usr/local && git reset --hard
Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

xml2-config
xmlcatalog
xmllint
xslt-config
xsltproc

Consider amending your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin in your PATH.
```

I even added the following to my config/environments/development.rb file

```
 Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin"
```

I uninstalled Imagemagick again and reinstalled it. Now I get the following link errors.

```
==> Installing imagemagick dependency: jpeg
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/sudo) is setuid or setgid
==> Downloading http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8d.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/jpeg-8d.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d
==> make install
Error: The linking step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link jpeg'
==> Summary
/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d: 18 files, 1.3M, built in 16 seconds
==> Installing imagemagick dependency: libtiff
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/sudo) is setuid or setgid
==> Downloading http://download.osgeo.org/libtiff/tiff-4.0.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libtiff-4.0.2.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/4.0.2
==> make install
Error: The linking step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link libtiff'
==> Summary
/usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/4.0.2: 241 files, 3.6M, built in 24 seconds
Error: You must `brew link jpeg' before little-cms can be installed
```

When I type brew link jpeg

```
Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8c
```

When I type brew link libtiff

```
Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/3.9.5
```

So in summary the links are looking for older versions of jpeg (8c instead of 8d) and libtiff (3.9.5 instead of 4.0.2)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This looks very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537011/imagemagick-issue-on-lion-installed-with-homebrew

Comment: I reinstalled developer tools and even installed the latest version of xcode 4.4

Comment: Sorry not using a mac at home so can't really help. I vaguely remember a friend having a similar problem, I might be able to dig something up next time I chat with her.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally fix it with 2 commands. Simple symbolic link, seems pretty hackish...

jpeg fix

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg

ln -s 8d 8c
```

libtiff fix

```
/usr/local/Cellar/libtiff

ln -s 4.0.2 3.9.5
```

Comment: After not being able to link or unlink pkg-config using:
  brew link pkg-config

I did the same:

  /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config
  ln -s 0.27 0.25