# rails installing spree not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, spree

## error

```
/Users/Username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spree_cmd-1.2.0/lib/spree_cmd/installer.rb:189: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/mysql/bin in PATH, mode 040777
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/identify
  Reason: Incompatible library version: identify requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 13.0.0
sh: line 1:   212 Trace/BPT trap          identify -version > /dev/null
Image magick must be installed.
```

## doubt

I have already installed latest version of imagemagick using homebrew , but still facing the same error. please help , thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get the same error when you type "identify" or "convert" in your terminal? Seems like an ImageMagick issue rather than spree.

Comment: yea i am getting the same error with both the commands ,and i am running 10.6.8 snow leopard ,and my system is up to date but still i am getting the same errors

Answer (score 2):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537011/imagemagick-issue-on-lion-installed-with-homebrew) :

> I ran into the same issue. Running a software update on the operating system resolved it for me. The version of libfree is out of date. Paperclip, ImageMagick and Homebrew were all working fine.

So try updating your OS and then re-install magick :

```
brew update
brew remove imagemagick
brew install imagemagick
```

Comment: still getting the same error , after reinstalling imagemagick by brew , do i have to do something else aswell?

Comment: maybe re-install the gem too? I doubt it has any effect since the gem is calling the command line tool.. You still get the very same error  `identify requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 13.0.0` ?